# Flutter: "(path): must not be null" on conditional file checks

Tags: image, flutter, null

I am trying to have a background to my application that either the user has chosen previously, or to use a default image if no file is found.

The code is very simple:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.blueAccent,
  image: DecorationImage(
    image: File(customImageFile).existsSync() ? FileImage(File(customImageFile)) : backgroundImage,
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
  ),
),
```

The application crashes on the conditional line, saying that (path): Must not be null.   I have tried many ways to get around this, but what I am specifically saying there is "if the file path is null, don't use it.   Use this image I made earlier for you".   But then it gets upset anyway.

Is there another way I can achieve the intended result here?

Edit:

As requested by @Vikas, more complete sample of code involved:

```
ImageProvider backgroundImage;
String themeLoader = 'blueTheme';
String customImageFile;
```

// Declaration

```
void initState() {
  _loadThemeSettings();
  super.initState();
}
```

// Initialisation

```
_loadThemeSettings() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  themeLoader = prefs.getString('themeColour' ?? 'blueTheme');
  customImageFile = prefs.getString('customImageFile' ?? 'empty')
  if (customImageFile != null) {
    if(File(customImageFile).existsSync()) {
      prefs.setString('customImageFile', customImageFile);
    } else {
      print('Path not valid');
    }
  } else {
    print('customImageFile is NULL');
  }

    if (themeLoader != null) {
          switch (themeLoader) {
            case 'blueTheme':
              {
                colorBloc.changeColor('blueTheme');
                setState(() {
                  backgroundImage = ExactAssetImage('lib/images/bg_blue_new.jpg');
                  buttonTheme = AppState.blueTheme;
                }
              }
              break;

            } else {
              print('Theme loader was NULL');
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

// Loading previously selected themes at run time.   There are several colours here in the case statement, but they are all identical and you get the idea.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
  child: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: BlocProvider<ColorBloc>(
        bloc: colorBloc,
        child: Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: (customImageFile != null && File(customImageFile).existsSync()) ? FileImage(File(customImageFile)) : backgroundImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
```

// that's where it sits, everything else works fine.   The rest of the build method is not relevant to this issue, and is working, but here it is anyway:

```
                    child: SafeArea(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              themesVisible == true
                                  ? SizedBox()
                                  : buttonRow(),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            child: topMenuRow(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<CustomToggleBloc>(
                  bloc: customToggleBloc,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        child: themesVisible == true ? singlePlayerThemes(singlePlayerCallbacks: callBacks) : scoreText(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),//bloc
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does it happen if you only set the image to be the background image like this `image:  backgroundImage, ` ?

Comment: No it doesn't.   It just breaks when I try the conditional.  Like just immediately seems to hate the method, completely independent of whether or not customImageFile is null.  It's like it doesn't try, it just says "hey you can't do it this way" but I don't really understand why not.

Comment: You are checking for File(customImageFile). In this, if customImageFile is null, then you are gonna get this error. So instead of that put condition as `(customImageFile != null && File(CustomImageFile).existsSync())` ? .... and then evaluate.

Comment: I still get an error when doing it this way.  Have edited my question to include all the changes and the error being reported.  Thanks @Vikas.

Comment: Hey, can you also post backgroundImage and parent widget for the one this decoration is for?

Comment: Thanks @Vikas, I have added more of the surrounding code in, as requested.

Comment: From what I can understand, I think backgroundImage is null and it tries to set it off. This might be if path is not correct for it. You should check if it renders the background image properly.

Comment: So I should just give it a starting file in the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

The `String path` in [File](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/File.html) constructor is non-nullable. The issue here is that even with the null-checks, a potentially null `customImageFile` is still used on `File(String path)`. As a workaround, you can set a placeholder image path if the image from the path is null.